# AttributeError: 'pygame.key.ScancodeWrapper' object has no attribute 'x'

Tags: python, pygame

The code is meant to be two-player spaceship game.

```
import pygame 
import os


# important window variables
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('GAME')

# COLOURS
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

# other important variables:
BORDER = pygame.Rect(WIDTH/2 - 19, 0, 10, (HEIGHT))
FPS = 120
VEL = 5    
SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT = 55, 40

# all image uploads
SPACE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets', 'space.png'))
RED_SPACESHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets', 'spaceship_red.png'))
YELLOW_SPACESHIP = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets', 'spaceship_yellow.png'))

# fitted images
RED_SPACESHIP1 = pygame.transform.scale(RED_SPACESHIP, (SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT))
YELLOW_SPACESHP2 = pygame.transform.scale(YELLOW_SPACESHIP, (SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT))
SPACE1 = pygame.transform.scale(SPACE, (WIDTH, HEIGHT))

# FINAL IMAGES
RED_SPACESHIP_FINAL = pygame.transform.rotate(RED_SPACESHIP1, 90)
YELLOW_SPACESHIP_FINAL = pygame.transform.rotate(YELLOW_SPACESHP2, -90)


def display(RED, YELLOW):
    """Display the current state (what shows up on the screen)."""
    SCREEN.fill(WHITE)    
    SCREEN.blit(SPACE, (0, 0))

    pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, BLACK, BORDER)

    SCREEN.blit(RED_SPACESHIP_FINAL, (RED.x, RED.y))
    SCREEN.blit(YELLOW_SPACESHIP_FINAL, (YELLOW.x, YELLOW.y))
    
    pygame.display.update()


def yellow_movement(keys_pressed, YELLOW):
     """Move the yellow ship."""
     keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

     if keys_pressed[pygame.K_UP]: # UP (RIGHT SIDE)
            YELLOW.y -= VEL
     if keys_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]: # DOWN (RIGHT SIDE)
            YELLOW.y += VEL
     if keys_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:  # RIGHT (RIGHT SIDE)
            YELLOW.x += VEL
     if keys_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:   # LEFT (RIGHT SIDE)
            YELLOW.x -= VEL


def red_movement(keys_pressed, RED):
        """Move the red starship."""
        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if  keys_pressed[pygame.K_w]: # UP (left side)
            RED.y -= VEL
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_s]: # DOWN (left side)
            RED.y += VEL
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_d]: # RIGHT (left side)
            RED.x += VEL
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_a]: # LEFT (left side)
            RED.x -= VEL
        

def main():
    """Run the game (main entrypoint)."""
    RED = pygame.Rect(100, 230, SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)    
    YELLOW = pygame.Rect(700, 230, SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    run = True    
    while run:    
        clock.tick(FPS)    

        for event in pygame.event.get():    
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:                    
                run = False
        
        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
       
        yellow_movement(YELLOW, keys_pressed)    
        red_movement(RED, keys_pressed)
             
        display(RED, YELLOW)

    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback error

Comment: here: AttributeError: 'pygame.key.ScancodeWrapper' object has no attribute 'x'

Answer (score 0):

The functions `red_movement` and `yellow_movement` are defined such that they take `keys_pressed` as the first argument and the spaceship as the second argument. But you pass first the spaceship and then `keys_pressed` as an argument into those functions. You should therefore swap the arguments in the function definition or when they are passed into the function.